# What does "keep getting better" mean in the movie Ratatouille?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the movie, there is a scene where Remy (the rat) is bashed and has to run down the sewerage. In conclusion, he says: "I was reminded how fragile it all was. How the world really saw me. **And it just kept getting better.**"

I don't understand the last sentence in this context. It should be worse isn't it?

Below are the script and screenshot:

> People on the street: Rat!
>   (PEOPLE SCREAMING)
>   Woman: Disgusting little creatures.
>   Remy: I was reminded how fragile it all was. How the world really saw me. **And it just kept getting better.**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, things ARE getting worse for the rat, and his "And it just kept getting better!" is ironic.  See the more complete answer from James K below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "irony".  What is said is almost the opposite from the underlying meaning. You only know this from the context (things keep getting worse). It is used for rhetorical effect.

You might hear idioms like "Well, that's just great(!)" meaning "That's terrible", for example. But using irony is difficult as understanding it depends on subtle intonation, body language and situational clues. In the movie, listen for a "rising then falling tone" as Remi says "And it just kept getting better".  The use of the word "just" also points to an ironical interpretation.